# Android MapView Changing in Another View

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have two activity groups that contain a list that go to a detail view.  The detail activty extends a mapactivity.  Once I set the lat/long and add the point and center it everything works great.  If I go to the other activity to do the same thing, both maps are changing with each lat/long change.  The code and view xml are seperate, so why are both maps changing to the same lat/long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for MapActivity](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html?com/google/android/maps/MapActivity.html), it says: *only one MapActivity is supported per process*. Ignoring this causes all sorts of problems besides the ones you are experiencing. The workaround is to put one of the MapActivities in a separate process. To do this modify the manifest entry for one of your activities and add the `android:process` attribute, like:

```
<activity android:name="MapActivity2" android:process=":MapActivity2">
```

Note that there are downsides to putting one of the activities in a separate process.

Comment: Basically what I did was rest the mapview point in the onResume() method which repopulated the map.  Thanks for the direction!